# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'app' : TensorFlow Image Classifier

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, python-3.6, attributeerror

I am trying to train a new model, based on my custom dataset of images, so it can be my personalized image classifier.

I strictly followed the tutorial from this link: "https://medium.com/@teavanist/image-classification-using-tensorflow-on-docker-windows-bd7824b05fee", which is actually an update from Siraj's video from about 3 years ago.

I've done eveyrthing, but when I get to the re-training process to complete the transfer learning, I get this Attribute Error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0] + unparsed] AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'app'
```

I saw somewhere that the argv method is infact a new method, and it's being used on an older version of python. I've updated to the latest one currently (Python 3.7.4), and it still doesn't work.

I also tried giving the arguments a null value in the retrain.py in the scripts folder, so it'll set a default, but it still show's the app error.

Please help, I strongly want this to work! Been trying for days now.

Or at the very least, recommend me to somewhere I can re-train with Google's inception and use my own image collection. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

TF Version issue

Please follow below links for Transfer learning on Image classification with Inception

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cpb102-txf-learning/index.html#0

https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/tutorials/image_retraining